# implement angular2 route URl with question mark

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular 2 and stuck in one of the functionality.

I have a Component to view a timer. It has few fields  like name description for the timer. I want to use the same component for editing these details.

I want to implement URL as

http://example.com/{timerID}?edit

http://example.com/{timerId}?view

How to achieve this using angular 2 router.
I could not found any example that uses this kind of URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a "token" like ":id" in your home routing option like described here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html - Just add the id to your route directive in the link: [routerLink]="['/', timerId]"

Comment: As for "edit" and "view": These are query parameters, just use the following directive in your link: [queryParams]="{edit: 1}"

Comment: this will make my URL http://example.com/{timerID}?edit=1 . Is there a way to have URl just like   http://example.com/{timerId}?edit

Comment: Complete example: <a [routerLink]="['/', timerId]" [queryParams]="{edit: 1"} routerLinkActive="active">

Comment: "Is there a way to have URl just like example.com{timerId}?edit" -> None that I know of, sry. You could try "mode=edit" or "mode=view" alternatively.